# CKEditor side by side

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to have two instances of CKeditor - one on the left side and one on the right side of the webpage. It should be [framed editors](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out this way. I wonder if it is possible to do it **only with CSS**, that is **without a table**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
table {
width: 100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table >
 <tr>
  <td><textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea></td> 
  <td><textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor2"></textarea></td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```